# Realizando consulta no AD (Active Directory) com PHP

Tags: php, windows, active-directory

Atualmente tenho no aqui no ambiente o **AD** (Active Directory) do Windows Server 2012. Hoje na minha aplicação em PHP já consigo realizar a conexão com esse AD via **ldap_connect** + **ldap_bind**.

Porém gostaria de realizar uma consulta dentro do AD. Buscar por exemplo o campo displayName, mail ou qualquer atributo contido na aba Attribute Editor.

Já localizei no manual do PHP **ldap_search**, porém não consegui fazer funcionar corretamente. Sem contar que não sei se essa função seria a correta para o meu caso.

Obrigado.

**EDIT-- Data:27/04/2015.**

Consegui realizar a consulta, veja o como ficou meu código:

```
$filtro = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(displayname=*)(sAMAccountname=$login1))";
$mostrar = array("samaccountname");
if (!($busca=@ldap_search($connect, $base_dn, $filtro, $mostrar))){
    die("Não foi possível realizar busca no Active Directory");
}
$info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $busca);
echo "<pre>".print_r($info,true)."</pre>";exit;
```

Comment: não vou colocar como resposta mas tem essa resposta na versão inglês do SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471771/getting-the-users-full-name-from-active-directory-using-php

Comment: Obrigado user3632930, ajudou bastante, porém não sei se estou fazendo algo de errado, mas estou pegando todos os usuários do AD, eu só queria as informações do usuário que está se logando! Veja o meu código como está: [http://pastebin.com/7iEFjdrS](http://pastebin.com/7iEFjdrS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui realizar a consulta, veja o como ficou meu código:

```
$filtro = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(displayname=*)(sAMAccountname=$login1))";
$mostrar = array("samaccountname");
if (!($busca=@ldap_search($connect, $base_dn, $filtro, $mostrar))){
    die("Não foi possível realizar busca no Active Directory");
}
$info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $busca);
echo "<pre>".print_r($info,true)."</pre>";exit;
```